# How to treat files generated by mfplain?

Tags: fonts, metapost, metafont

Metapost can treat Metafont sources with mfplain.

Example:

```
mpost -mem=mfplain cmr10.mf
```

Then each glyph is output in separate file like this:

```
cmr10.0
cmr10.1
cmr10.2
...
```

I cannot find any tutorial how to use these files. How can I import them into FontForge? Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

metapost output is PostScript.

You can look at the files in any text editor, eg `cmr.65` starts

```
%!PS
%%BoundingBox: -1 -90 270 270 
%%HiResBoundingBox: -0.2 -89.86356 269.1912 269.19066 
%%Creator: MetaPost 2.02
%%CreationDate: 2023.06.25:1932
%%Pages: 1
%*Font: cmr10 9.96265 9.96265 30:fe000000000078082
%%BeginProlog
%%EndProlog
%%Page: 1 1
 0.7 0.7 0.7 setrgbcolor
newpath 123.94922 209.95695 moveto
...
```

and looking at in `gv` (ghostscript)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. :) Do you know how to get the Postscript instructions into a font editor?

Comment: @WeißerKater no personal experience but https://fontforge.org/docs/tutorial/importexample.html